# Add an image to AVPlayerViewController in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, avfoundation, sdwebimage

I am trying to add an image to AVPlayerViewController contentOverlayView, according to the indexPath of the UICollectionView.

I want the app to play audio with a particular background image according to the UICollectioView indexPath when the user selects the item at a particular indexPath, I am receiving the audio file and image from API and I am using SDWebImage library to download the image from URL.

Here's my collectionView shouldSelectItemAt indexPath code :

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    SVProgressHUD.show()
    if let Url =  URL(string: musicData[indexPath.row].musicCellAudioFile) {
        let musicfileURL = Url
        let audioPlayer = AVPlayer(url: musicfileURL)
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = audioPlayer
        controller.player = audioPlayer
        present(controller, animated: true) {

            audioPlayer.play()

        }
        controller.contentOverlayView?.addSubview(imageFromUrl(musicImageUrlString: musicData[indexPath.row].musicImage))

         controller.contentOverlayView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 178/255, green: 178/255, blue: 122/255, alpha: 1)



    }else{
        print("NO music file")
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }


    return true
}
```

Here's my imageFromUrl method :

```
func imageFromUrl(musicImageUrlString:String) -> UIImageView{

    let image = UIImage()
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: musicImageUrlString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"),options:SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    })
    return imageView


}
```

Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a completion block that returns the image itself. So you just need to set the image there.

```
func imageFromUrl(musicImageUrlString:String) -> UIImageView {

        let image = UIImage()
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: musicImageUrlString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"),options:SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            imageView.image = image
        })
        return imageView
    }
```

**Update**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

        SVProgressHUD.show()

        if let Url =  URL(string: musicData[indexPath.row].musicCellAudioFile) {
            let musicfileURL = Url
            let audioPlayer = AVPlayer(url: musicfileURL)
            let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
            controller.player = audioPlayer
            controller.player = audioPlayer
            imageFromUrl(musicImageUrlString: "your URL") { (imageView) in
                guard let imageView = imageView else { return }
                controller.contentOverlayView?.addSubview(imageView)
                controller.contentOverlayView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 178/255, green: 178/255, blue: 122/255, alpha: 1)
                present(controller, animated: true) {
                    audioPlayer.play()
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            print("NO music file")
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }

        return true
    }
```

And your function

```
typealias closure = (UIImageView?) -> Void

func imageFromUrl(musicImageUrlString:String, completion: @escaping closure) {
    let image = UIImage()
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: musicImageUrlString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"),options:SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
        imageView.image = image
        completion(imageView)
    })
}
```

Comment: I have tried your answer but still, there is no image on AVPlayerViewController overlay view

Comment: I haven't used sdwebimage before but form the documentation I can see that it downloads and sets images async. In your case the imageView is being returned before the image has been set by sdWebImage. So you need to add a dispatch group to return the image view only after it has been downloaded and set

Comment: Can you help me with dispatch group?

Comment: I think you will be better off just using a completion block. See my update.

Comment: I have tried your code, but the image doesn't appear. I make a print statement for the image in which it shows that the frame = (0 0; 0 0).